# How to show percentage of scan completion of webroot in background

Tags: powershell, automation, antivirus

I am silently scanning the entire system using webroot in the background. powershell is used to run the webroot in the background. The scanning is happening but I want to show to the user how much percentage is complete.

Like

```
 1% Complete.
 2% Complete.
 .
 .
 .
 100% Complete.
```

I tried `$scan=Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Webroot\WRSA.exe" -ArgumentList '-silentscan="c:\"'`.

The system is scanning in the background but I am not able to fetch the status.